# Arithmetic of Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic

if $k$ is a field and $f,g,h$ are polynomials such that $f=g+h$, then a polynomial that divides two of the three will divide the third.

I'm having trouble showing doing the problem as polynomials.  I know how to do it is $f,g,h$ are integers.

Comment: What is your proof for integers? Chances are that it could work for polynomials with minimal changes, if at all.

Comment: The proof is the same in any commutative ring since the definition of divisibility is the same, as are the arithmetic laws employed (ring axioms, associate, commutative, distribute laws etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it the usual way (as for integers):

If $p$ is a polynomial over $k$ dividing both $g,h$ this means that $\frac{g}{p}$, $\frac{h}{p}$ are also polynomials over $k$. Thus:
$$
\frac{f}{p}=\frac{g+h}{p}=\frac{g}{p}+\frac{h}{p}
$$
is also a polynomial over $k$. This means that $p$ also divides $f$.